# CodeIgniter: Adding to where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I have the following condition in ExpressionEngine (which is using CodeIgniter framework):

```
if ($group_id !== '')
    {
        $this->db->where("members.group_id", $group_id);
    }
```

I´d like to add an extra condition to that where (an AND), how can I do this? Do I add a new `$this->db->where('my_field', $my_value)`? Or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it.

```
if ($group_id !== '')
{
    $this->db->where("members.group_id", $group_id);
    $this->db->where('my_field', $my_value);
}
```

Check Codeigniter documentation http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html
It's good.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if (is_numeric($group_id) && $group_id > 0)
if ($group_id)
{
    $this->db->where("members.group_id", $group_id);
    $this->db->where('my_field', $my_value);
    // $this->db->where('my_field >=', $my_value);
    // $this->db->where('my_field <', $my_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do is write out the query such as:

```
$data = array('name' => $_POST['name'], 'lname' => $_POST['lname']);
$sql = "select table where name = ? and lname = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, $data);
```

the reason why i prefer to write it out is because once you end up writing very complex queries with many table joins it becomes really difficult to read active record queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yah.....u can try this:

```
if ($group_id !== '')
{
    $this->db->where("members.group_id", $group_id);
    $this->db->where('my_field', $my_value);
}
```

u can also use:

```
$this->db->or_where('my_field',$my_value);
```